# 404 Not found Spring boot war to Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have Spring boot applicatio. This works fine with embedded server. And i can use Postman to test API.

Now i want deploy this on Tomcat 8 i create root.war file with `maven install`
and put it to Tomcat/webapps/ 
I run tomcat without any errors. But when i use the same url as postman it gives me 404 not found.

Example of url i use for both(embedded and tomcat): `localhost:8080/auth/registration`

I've tried to set `server.context-path` in application.properties but no result.

I believe that problem is in configuration of project.

Here is my pom.xml

```
parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dependency for singleton-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--PostgreSQL driver-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--SEND MAIL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Amazon-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.331</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>





<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
    <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

**EDITED**

Also i have found that spring boot can be compiled to JAR as better way than war. If it's better how to change pom.xml for compiling in jar.

So i've tried to create jar as suggested below. I run this with `java -jar` and got
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.http.encoding-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/ValidationException`

```
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.ValidationException
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94) ~[rehapp-api.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
... 83 common frames omitted
```

Comment: instead of auth in "localhost:8080/auth/registration " check with localhost:8080/root/registration

Comment: It doesn't work. Anyway what war is "root" name you don't need to set /root

Answer (score 6):

## Step1:

Add/Update the following dependency to `pom.xml` (scope as `provided`) in order to tell Spring Boot not to use its embedded Tomcat.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

## Step2:

```
<properties>
      <packaging>war</packaging>
</properties>
```

## Step3:

SpringBootApplication class should look like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Reference: [Create deployable-war-file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) and [Maven Packaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging)

Comment: It worked! But i did not understand. I saw many examples without extend it. Why still i have to extend? Can we solve it via different way?

Answer (score 0):

```
add these in pom.xml

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.muna.manas</groupId>
<artifactId>core-java</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

The most important aspect here is the type – to create an executable jar, double check the configuration uses a jar type.

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>
                    org.baeldung.executable.ExecutableMavenJar
                </mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: main class is Spring boot starter class?

Comment: When i run JAR(java -jar name.jar) i have 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.ValidationException