# Deploy Spring App to Tomcat without web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I have successfully tested my war file with embedded TOMCAT and it works fine. Now I want to deploy it to TOMCAT but I keep getting a **404 error**.

The URL I navigate to on the browser is
http://localhost:9999/springrest/demo/users/all

My TOMCAT uses the port **9999**

My **JRE_HOME** version is **1.8.0_261**

My **pom.xml** has **<java.version>1.8</java.version>**

TOMCAT manager shows the app as running
[image]

My Controller code is as follows

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
  public class UserController {

  @Autowired 
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @GetMapping(path="/users/all")
  public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
  // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
  return userRepository.findAll();
  }

}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<groupId>com.eptc</groupId>
<artifactId>springrest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springrest</name>
<description>Rest API for mobile app</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>    
<start-class>com.eptc.springrest.SpringrestApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency> 
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why, specifically, do you want to deploy in an external Tomcat?

Comment: We have a server at work running LINUX CentOS. I have to use that server since the DATABASE records to be used for production are on it.

Comment: So? You don't need an external Tomcat; you can just use `java -jar`. Spring Boot even has support for creating a standalone service descriptor so you can run it from init. (Though Docker might be a bit simpler for something like this, and it's also pretty easy to run on a Linux server like that.)

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- So I just dump my war inside my **www** folder, use **java -jar** to run it and hit **www.myhostname.com/demo/users/all** in my browser?

Comment: Have you read the [offical documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-traditional-deployment) which explains what to do? Also **which** Tomcat version are you deploying to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my **Apache Tomcat version** to Apache Tomcat **8.5.58** and it worked like a charm.
The Springboot banner even shows on cmd on running **catalina.bat run**

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the Servlet context required by Tomcat by implementing the SpringBootServletInitializer interface?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTomcatApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Please refer this link for the details :[Deploy a Spring Boot WAR into a Tomcat Server](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy)

Comment: Yes I have. I also did the **@Override** on the **configure** method

Comment: I followed that exact Tutorial

Comment: @RynohRR what is the name of the war ? is it springrest? have you tried  http://localhost:9999/springrest/demo/users/all ?

Comment: Yes, It is springrest. From the build log I get.... Building war: C:\Users\similem\Documents\dev\Java\Spring\springrest\target\springrest.war

Comment: Can you please share you pom file?

Comment: Please also refer this , have you covered all of this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50506960/404-not-found-spring-boot-war-to-tomcat